# Can't put a new item in an existing DynamoDB Table using Lamda Python 3.6 Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm having trouble putting a new item to my DynamoDB Table.
I'm programming directly in AWS Lambda.

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-central-1')

    dynamodb.putItem{
        "TableName": "myTable",
        "Item": {
            "username": {
                "S": "chicken"
            },
            "fav_food": {
                "S": "ketchup"
            }
        }
    }
    return 0
```

Comment: What's the error exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
table = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=region).Table(table_name)
item = { 
    "username" : "chicken", 
    "fav_food" : "ketchup" 
}
table.put_item(Item=item)
```

If you post the gotten error it will help a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do a put_item:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name='eu-central-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('myTable')
            table.put_item(
               Item={
                    'username': "chicken",
                    'fav_food': "ketchup"
                    }
                )
```

Comment: Forgotten " before chicken